# Where to write error message while using error blade directive?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In the code below, I just want to know, where is "$message" is written or stored?

```
<label for="title">Post Title</label>

<input id="title" type="text" class="@error('title') is-invalid @enderror">

@error('title')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: $message will be return back in your request data which generally stored in the request/session data.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

*From the Laravel Docs* https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages

## The @error Directive

You may also use the `@error` Blade directive to quickly check if validation error messages exist for a given attribute. Within an `@error` directive, you may echo the `$message` variable to display the error message